# POI corrupts file when writing twice to output stream

Tags: java, apache-poi

My requirement is to create a workbook object and then saves a xlsx file to the file system and then sends the same workbook object as an email attachment.

What i did:

create a workbook object:

```
XSSFWorkbook workBook = excelGenerator.createWorkBook(output);
 saveToFile(input, workBook);
 mailSender.sendNotificationWithAttachment(input, excelGenerator.saveToByteArray(workBook), emailId);
```

where saveToFile():

```
File metricFile = new File(metricsDirectory, filename + ".xlsx");
 try{
     FileOutputStream fileOut =new FileOutputStream(metricFile);
     workBook.write(fileOut);
     fileOut.flush();
     fileOut.close();
 }
```

saveToByteArray():

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 try {
     workBook.write(byteOutputStream);
 } catch (IOException e) {
 }
 return byteOutputStream;
```

1. If i First write the stream to file and then send the byteArrayOutputStream as an attachment, then attachment got corrupt and when i open it gave me a warning that file is corrupt and if i say ok it open the file correctly. and generated file is perfectly fine.
2. If I First send the attachment and then save the excel to file system. then attachment remains ok and opens normally but the file on file system got corrupt

That is when i write the same workbook twice, It corrupts the second occurrence of write.

I also try to pass different workbook object to both steps, In that case it works normally.

I am looking for a solution where i can copy the XSSFWorkbook object or its content to a separate object before writing to another excel.

Currently i used a workaround to reload the same excel file after writing it to file

```
     workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(metricFile));
```

Comment: Are you using Java 7+? If yes, why don't you use java.nio.file?

Comment: which version of POI do you use?

Comment: I am using POI 3.10 and yes i used JAVA 7, I guess the problem is with poi workbook write method. Or should i try with nio.file first

Comment: problem is not related to nio package. Should figure out how to use `write` method twice without corruptions.Because you use same object for calling `write` method that may cause the issue

Comment: @ViMatviichuk yup, that's not nio related, but it is another problem that new code written in 2015 still uses File. java.nio.file is 4 years old now and is miles better.

Comment: Its because i hardly have the scenarios in long time to use file objects, I will make it a practise to use nio instead of io. Also here you find me closing the resources manually rather than JAVA ARM feature. Thats because this code was migrated from java 6. But that is a different question.                              I also find in various questions/forums that its a POI bug while writing the same object twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description this really sounds like a POI-bug that has also bitten me recently, namely [this one](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56468). It is fixed in POI 3.11-beta1 and on 21.12.2014 a stable 3.11-version of POI has been released. So I think you best strategy would be to upgrade your POI-version instead of trying to produce some hack to work around the problem.

Comment: Thanks seems to be working fine with POI 3.11 version